# Spring Security OAuth - Supporting multiple authentication types

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to set up a microservice that is only dedicated for authentication. There is a API gateway sit in-front which sends  all types of authentications to the single endpoint I will have (/auth) inside this microservice. Currently, there are few scenarios I need to consider:

1. When the user passes in username & password: I verify the credentials and send back JWT.
2. When the user passes in api key & secret: I verify the validity of api key & secret, and send back JWT.
3. When the user passes in client_id: I verify the validity of client_id, and send back JWT.
4. When the user passes in JWT: I verify JWT and return either success/fail response to API gateway, so that it can proceed to call the other microservices.

For every authentication requests, it will be one of these types. Would having multiple filters and authentication providers work in this case? I couldn't really find a good example on it, if anyone can guide me through this, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you!